(MSBuild / Visual Studio 2022 C++ / Property sheets) Prevent a CopyFile item to be displayed and/or modified from IDE
I created this property sheet which works fine:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <CopyFileToFolders Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin">
      <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
      <FileType>Document</FileType>
      <DestinationFolders>$(OutDir)</DestinationFolders>
    </CopyFileToFolders>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

When I add this property sheet to a project, Visual Studio IDE displays in solution explorer a new item "somefile.bin"  whose properties can be edited, and this edition modifies the property sheet file itself. Is there a way to write the same behavior in the property sheet that would prevent IDE from displaying the item or forbid its edition ?
-
My problem context: I am working in a multi-projects team solution. My project provides a property sheet to be used by my coworkers projects. The file is placed in an “Include” directory. Usually, referencing a property sheet is transparent, like any header include, but not in this case. I would like to prevent my coworkers to unintentionnally modify the shared property sheet file, thinking editing the displayed items would impact only their own project files.
I tried below options without success:
1. Make the property sheet "read-only" by using:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ReadOnlyProject>true</ReadOnlyProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

But it applied to the entire project, not only the property sheet file.
2. Use a target:
  <Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="Build" Outputs="$(OutDir)somefile.bin">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="MyTarget: copy/update files '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin' to '$(OutDir)'" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"/>
  </Target>

But it does not perform file version checking, i.e. if I modify the source file or delete the output file, "MyTarget" is not necessarily triggered, project can stay in "up-to-date" state and output file is not updated.
3. Workaroung by setting the file as "read-only":

Git does not support read-only files, checkouts removes the
read-only property.
When editing the added item property page, instead of appearing greyed, one can modify properties and IDE shows a "write anyway Yes/No message". Even if it informs the developer, it is still a bit unsafe as we can easily click 'Yes'. Fun fact: if we select 'cancel', an error message appears...

4. Workaround by using a target + DisableFastUpToDateCheck (from Dou Xu-MSFT idear)
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>True</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="Build" Outputs="$(OutDir)somefile.bin">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="MyTarget: copy/update files '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin' to '$(OutDir)'" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"/>
  </Target>

But this option does not suit me:

Disabling ‘up-to-date’ state is invasive for my coworkers projects.
We have more than 50 projects in our solution, without ‘up-to-date’ optimization, quick-build will be very verbose and not so quick.
Even if “somefile.bin” has not changed, file copy is performed and associated message is printed on output window.

On the contrary, CopyFileToFolders item do start the build process if-and-only-if “somefile.bin” has changed, project staying in ‘up-to-date’ state otherwise.
-
I finally workarounded by (I hope temporarily):

placing the property sheet file in a local directory/filter of the project which provides it
creating a post-build event in the providing project which copies the project-local file to an Include directory shared through the solution
referencing in other projects the file from the Include directory

Then, if another developer modifies the item properties from his project, it affects a file that will be reseted at next rebuild. N.B. it seems that the post-build copy does not break the ‘up-to-date’ check of dependent projects as, even if uselessly copied, the destination file time-stamp is not modified.
I hoped that a more elegant solution using property sheets syntax did exist. But maybe not...

Note: I also posted the question on Visual Studio developer community. See. link I'll keep current post updated.

If you  would like to prevent your coworkers to unintentionally modify the shared property sheet file, you can set property of .vcxproj file to Read-only.
Right click the file->Properties->General->Attributes.
If you use source control such as Git, you can create a .gitignore file and the following to it
# Ignore project file
projectname.vcxproj

When your coworkers modify the project file and commit to source control,  .gitignore helps prevent this file from being tracked by Git. In other words, all changes to this file are not committed, only stored locally. This ensures that this file can only be modified on your end.
UPDATE
About  the method "2. Use a target" you have tried, based on my test, i found that  if I modify the source file or delete the output file, "MyTarget" is triggered. It does perform file version checking.
Test result:

If your "MyTarget" is not necessarily triggered, please try to  set the property DisableFastUpToDateCheck to true in the project file.
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>True</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>


A boolean value that applies to Visual Studio only. The Visual Studio build manager uses a process called FastUpToDateCheck to determine whether a project must be rebuilt to be up to date. This process is faster than using MSBuild to determine this. Setting the DisableFastUpToDateCheck property to true lets you bypass the Visual Studio build manager and force it to use MSBuild to determine whether the project is up to date.

Docs referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022

Hi Dou Xu-MSFT, thank you for taking the time to analyse my problem. I definitely use git, but I also definitely need this property file to be referenced in git repository, so projects still compile for my coworkers.

Hi @Charly, please set DisableFastUpToDateCheck  to check if your  "MyTarget" is triggered. Updated the answer.

Hi Dou Xu-MSFT,
Unfortunately, disabling FastUpToDateCheck does not suit my needs. I updated my initial post with more details.
Thank you for your time and idears to help me on this issue.

Hi @Charly, i know your concerns. Another idea about "3. Workaround by setting the file as "read-only". Since git does not support read-only files, you don't need  set the file to  read-only. If you don't want your collaborators unintentionally modify the shared property sheet file, you can manage it in the git repo, where only you can modify it. Other colleagues' modifications will only be stored locally and will not be submitted to git. Once you modify the file, you can notify your colleagues to run git pull in time to get the latest changes.

Hi @Dou Xu-MSFT, do you mean: I put "manually" the file in repos and in the meantime I exclude it in the .gitignore to prevent any update ? Then everyone can fetch/pull the file but nobody can modify+push it ? Mmmm interesting. I think my current workaround is more maintainable but your idear is still nice :)

Yes., everyone can fetch/pull the file but nobody can modify+push it. At present, your workaround may be more suitable for your case.
